# Trash Bin for Categories?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, wpdb, wp-update-post

I have a cat_notice taxonomy, where there are several categories and one of them the slug is 'trash'. In this case I created a link and I needed that when I clicked on this link I would take the current id of the term and add it as a child of the term 'trash'.

```
add_filter( "cat_notice_row_actions", 'trash_row_actions', 10, 2 );
  function trash_row_actions( $actions, $user_object ) {
     // Remove the Edit action.
     unset( $actions['delete'] );
     $termID = $user_object->term_id;
     $termTrash = get_term_by('slug', 'lixeira', 'cat_notice');
     $idTerm = $termTrash->term_id;  
     wp_update_term( $termID, $user_object, array( 'parent' => $termTrash ) );
     $actions['trash_lionx'] = '<a style="color: red" href="">Excluir</a>';
    return $actions;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Hi, thanks for edited post.
You cam know fixed this problem?
i try <pre>wp_update_term( $termID, 'cat_notice', array( 'parent' => $termTrash ) );</pre> this call using button, but not working again

Answer (score 0):

i finded solution for this:

```
add_filter( "cat_notice_row_actions", 'trash_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function trash_row_actions( $actions, $user_object ) {
    // Remove the Edit action.
    unset( $actions['delete'] );

    $catTrash = 10;
    $id = $user_object->term_id;
    $taxName = $user_object->taxonomy;
    $taxParent = $user_object->parent;
    
    // Add your custom action.

    $actions['update-parent'] = "<form action='#' method='get'>
            <input type='hidden' name='taxonomy' value='$taxName'>
            <input type='hidden' name='post_type' value='noticia'>
            <input type='hidden' name='termID' value='$id'>
            <input type='hidden' name='trashID' value='$catTrash'>
            <input type='submit' value='Excluir' onclick='add_trash_bin()'>
        </form>";
}
```

and after called my function:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_trash_bin' );
function add_trash_bin() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy';
    $id = isset($_GET['termID']) ? $_GET['termID'] : NULL;
    $taxName = isset($_GET['taxonomy']) ? $_GET['taxonomy'] : NULL;
    $trashID = isset($_GET['trashID']) ? $_GET['trashID'] : NULL;
    if($id <> NULL && $taxName <> NULL && $trashID <> NULL)
    {
        $wpdb->update(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'parent' => $trashID
            ), array(
                'term_id' => $id
            )
        );
        clean_taxonomy_cache( $taxName );
    } else {
        echo 'Dados incorretos';
    } }
```

So, i know missing error handling but its working.